# Common name for speech errors like Phoneme Deletion and Phoneme Substitution

Tags: terminology, spoken-language

I would like to know the common name for speech errors like phoneme deletion and phoneme substitution, just like there is word called "prosodic error" for stress error and intonation error. I have viewed the list for speech errors but can't find a common name.

Comment: They're not always errors. Many clusters are simplified and vowels are deleted or reduced in normal speech. There are many different phenomena that produce actual speech that varies from prototype phonation. Most of them are not errors, in the sense that they're not perceived as wrong or as meaning something else from what the speaker intended.

Comment: thanks for commenting! what is the first word comes to your mind if you don't want to list all phoneme insertion, phoneme deletion, phoneme distortion and phoneme substitution? there should be a word for all these even if they are not always errors...

Comment: Probably _dysfunction_; _speech dysfunction_, to be precise. _Momentaneous speech dysfunction_, to mean a harmless mistake. Though real mistakes will tend to be of certain types.